# What handler can be other than HandlerMethod in preHandle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

`HandlerInterceptor` defines the following method:

```java
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
```

In this method, the argument handler can be `instanceof HandlerMethod`, what else can it be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking `HandlerInterceptor#preHandle`.

The handler object that passes to it is determined by `HandlerMapping` , which map a `HttpServletRequest` to a `Handler` object. The logic of how this `Handler` object process the `HttpServletRequest`  is encapsulated inside `HandlerAdapter` which has a method called `supports()` to define which `Handler` object can this `HandlerAdapter` handle.

In other words , by looking at the `support()` in different `HandlerAdapter` 's implementations, you can see that the `Handler` Object can be :

- HandlerMethod
- HttpRequestHandler
- Controller
- Servlet
- WebServiceMessageReceiver'
- WsdlDefinition
- XsdSchema